# git rebase with the last commit on the branch

Tags: git, github

I have a git branch that has many commits and that was being merged with master regularly to resolve merge conflicts.

I wanted to rebase and did: `git rebase master` while on the branch, let's call it `test_branch`

but in order to rebase I have to resolve merge conflict on every commit.

Also when I `git log` I see mix of commit from master and test_branch and don't know how to squash properly

Is there a way I can remove all the commits on the branch, except the last one? And then rebasing it won't be even necessary

Edit: there is an open Pull Request on github, which ideally should be merged

Comment: Just [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commit you need.

Comment: @RomainValeri can I cherry pick from the same branch? because I have a PR on github and I dont want to close it

Comment: Very broadly : make a backup of your local branch, reset it to master, cherry-pick the commit you need here, then push with force, and finally refresh the PR. Okay, let me a minute, I'm making it an answer for the commands details.

Comment: Don't mix `merge` and `rebase` like that. Choose one strategy and stick to it. Did someone say you have to rebase? If not, just `merge`.. The history might be messy though

Comment: @vakio yes CTO told me to rebase and I am in agony

Comment: A rebase is a series of cherry-picks under the hood. Not saying that to make it worse, though. :-) If your CTO wants to avoid merge commits as much as possible, the cherry-pick way will make him happy in that regard. (As will Enrico's excellent mixed resetting answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can remove all the commits on the branch, except the last one?

Yes, more than one way, actually. Let's say that the history of your repo looks like this:

```sh
o---A---o---o (master)
     \       \
      B---C---M---D (test_branch)
```

An easy way to achieve what you want is to [*reset*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#_step_2_updating_the_index_mixed) `test_branch` to the [*fork point*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---fork-point) `A` while keeping all the changes in the working directory:

```sh
git switch test_branch
git reset $(git merge-base --fork-point master test_branch)
```

All the changes that were made in `test_branch` are now going to be in your working directory. At this point, you can simply make a new commit:

```sh
o---A---o---o (master)
     \
      E (test_branch)
```

Since you mentioned that you have a pull request open, you'll have to force push `test_branch` in order to update it on the remote:

```sh
git push -f
```

Note that commit `E` is also going to contain the changes that had come from the merges with `master` (`M` in our example). Depending on how you resolved those conflicts, you should be prepared to resolve more conflicts once you merge `test_branch` into `master`.

Comment: I think this is what OP wants, even though the other answer does what OP literally asked. :D

Comment: After `E` is created, maybe rebase it onto `master` to remove the stuff from all the `master` merges?

Answer (score 2):

One way to "fix" your PR if you need to keep it :
*(starting with your `test_branch` checked out locally)*

```
# make a backup
git branch backup_test_branch

# restart your branch from a clean master
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master

# get the needed commit on it
# here <hash> is the "last commit" you refered to
git cherry-pick <hash>

# if conflicts arise at this point, resolve them as usual.

# replace remote history of your branch (we have a backup, remember)
git push -f
```

Then refresh the PR to see your lone cherry-picked commit ready to be merged on `master`.

*(Note : at the cherry-pick step, if the commit you want is indeed the last on the branch, just do `git cherry-pick test_branch`)*